# How to make bot autorole when someone join voice channel?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

How can I make my bot give a role when a user joins a specific voice channel ?

```js
const team1role = message.guild.roles.find((role) => role.name === "Team 1");
const team1members = team1role.members;

const chan1 = message.guild.channels.find((channel) => channel.name === "Team 1")

team1members.forEach((member) => {
  member.setVoiceChannel(chan1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to go inside your main file (the same one as where you put your client.login(TOKEN) function) and create a new event :

```
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldState, newState) => {
    if (!newState.channel || !newState.member) return; // Triggered if the user left a channel
    const testChannel = newState.guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.name === 'Team 1');
    if (newState.channelID === testChannel.id) { // Triggered when the user joined the channel we tested for
        const role = newState.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === 'Team 1');
        if (!newState.member.roles.cache.has(role)) newState.member.roles.add(role); // Add the role to the user if they don't already have it
    }
});
```

Comment: @HypexBot I did forget a parenthesis on the last line. I edited my code, it should work better now

Comment: 'member' is no defined now.

Comment: this part  member.roles.add(role)

Comment: @HypexBot excuse me, I'm dumb tonight, it should be working now

Comment: @HypexBot Maybe with this another small fix I just applied ?

Comment: still same problem u can join my server for more proof

https://discord.gg/pWBWAn